# Why do i get different links for a specific route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I defined this route:

```
get "calendar/home/(:datum)", to: 'calendar#home', as: 'calendar'
```

So then i my view for `home#index` i call:

```
<%= link_to 'Kalender', calendar_path(Date.today.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")) %>
```

This links to:

```
http://localhost:3000/calendar/home?datum=24.11.2013
```

So now the strange thing in the view for `calender#home` i call:

```
  def home
@date = Date.parse(params[:datum])
@monday = @date.beginning_of_week
```

....

```
<%= link_to "Montag", calendar_path(@monday.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")), :class => "btn btn-primary" %>
```

Somehow this links to: Whitout `?datum=`

```
 http://localhost:3000/calendar/home/18.11.2013
```

And when i click this link i get the error message:

```
 No route matches [GET] "/calendar/home/18.11.2013"
```

So what did i wrong?

Comment: what is `@date` equal to here? - `@date = Date.parse(params[:datum])`

Comment: Can you try strftime("%d-%m-%Y") instead of strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

Comment: Yes that worked somehow! Can you please post it as answer @nishanthan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using strftime("%d.%m.%Y"), rails takes string after .(Dot) as format, So its better you can change it as strftime("%d-%m-%Y") or some thing else